# Netsuite tag - wrap span around total_formatted

Tags: html, tags, netsuite

I have this tag here, I'm working with an ad company that wants to wrap a span around the `line.get('total_formatted')`. I'm having trouble figuring this out. how should this look?

```
<%= _('$(0) $(1)').translate('<span class="amount-label">' + _('Amount:').translate() + '</span>', line.get('total_formatted')) %>
```

Comment: oo I think I can just take out the line and use it like this, <% line.get('total_formatted') %>

Comment: <%= _('$(0) $(1)').translate('<span class="amount-label">' + _('Amount:').translate() + '</span>') %>
     <span id="amoTotal"><% line.get('total_formatted') %></span>

Comment: no none of that works actually I need to be able to wrap the span from with in <%= _('$(0) $(1)').translate('<span class="amount-label">' + _('Amount:').translate() + '</span>', line.get('total_formatted')) %> but I can't seem to get it right. anyone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to wrap the same correctly. this is how I did it.

```
<%= _('$(0) $(1)').translate('<span class="amount-label">' + _('Amount:').translate() + '</span>' + '<span id='amoTotal'>', line.get('total_formatted') + '</span>') %>
```

works great no issues, console errors.